# How to access results of shopify-node-api request outside callback function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, shopify

I'm building a Shopify app and I'm running into an issue while using the shopify-node-api module. This is the code I'm working with:

```
collectProducts: ['storedProducts', function(results, callback) {

  const collected_products = results.storedProducts;

  for (var i = 0; i < collected_products.length; i++) {

    Shopify.post('/admin/collects.json', {
      "collect": {
        "product_id": collected_products[i].product_id,
        "collection_id": process.env.DAILY_COLLECTION
      }
    }, function(err, data, headers){
      collected_products[i].collect_id = data.collect.id;
    });
  }

  callback(null, collected_products);
}],
```

For clarity's sake, the `collectProducts` item is part of an async function. I'm trying to gather the collect ID from the response to the post request and update the `collect_id` value in `collected_products`. The issue is I can't seem to access the `collected_products` array from inside the callback function for the post request. Is there a way to 1. simply return that value for each iteration of the for loop or 2. access the `collected_products` array from within that callback function to store those values?

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: What is the value of collected_products inside the shopify.post callback, could you try to print it out?

Comment: It just shows as undefined. The specific error in the use case above is something like "Can't access attribute 'collect_id' of undefined".

Comment: Firstly, just make sure the the collect_id attribute exists in each collected_products array. Could you show me the console.log result of the exact collected_products inside Shopify.post() callback?

Comment: Yeah absolutely, it logs this twice - once for each iteration of the loop.

```[ 
  { 
    product_id: 10274628419,
    database_product_id: null,
    collect_id: null,
    title: 'Title',
    image: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1954/3027/products/A_title.jpg?v=1494608775'
  },
  {
    product_id: 10274666755,
    database_product_id: null,
    collect_id: null,
    title: 'Title',
    image: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1954/3027/products/A_title.jpg?v=1494608968'
  }
]```

Comment: Small update - if I assign the iteration index to a variable within the loop (` const theIndex = i;`) and use that to access the index instead it seems to work within the loop. So for example `console.log(collected_products[theIndex].collect_id);` outputs the correct value within the loop, but it doesn't seem to update the `collected_products` array outside the loop where I need it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling on this later, I was able to solve the issue by using the async module I had already been using for other parts of the app. The mapSeries function accomplished what I was trying to do.

```
// Get storedProducts from previous async function
async.mapSeries(results.storedProducts, function(product, cb) {
  // Adding the new collect here
  Shopify.post('/admin/collects.json', {
    "collect": {
      "product_id": product.product_id,
      "collection_id": process.env.DAILY_COLLECTION
    }
  }, function(err, data, headers) {
      // Update the product object with the Shopify-generated collect id
      product.collect_id = data.collect.id
      // Add the result to the mapSeries array
      cb(err, product);
    });
  }, function(err, results) {
    // Pass the now updated mapSeries array to the next async function
    callback(err, results);
});
```